# Salesforce: Efficient way to automatically assign Lead Owner to specific User if Account or Company name is such

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lead

I am new to SF and learning things as I go.

I am in a process to design automation for Lead Ownership assignment to specific User when Account or Company Name is 'X'. What should be the best approach Trigger, Workflow or Process Builder? Or do you have more suggestions?

I am thinking of the workflow route and interested in knowing the criteria.

Thanks,
Marci K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lead assignment rules.

https://www.salesforce.com/products/guide/lead-gen/routing-assignment-rules/ is a good start, especially links to trailhead, the self-paced trainings.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.customize_leadrules.htm&type=5 help article